# Paired barchart with missing groups is resulting in incorrect axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bit of a complex issue here. I am trying to create an anonymous, monthly comparison or bill rates by location. The goal is to create a graph like this which provides an anonymous visualization which can be distributed among the providers. the problem is, that in the graph below, the data for Corbin is actually the 3rd group from the bottom. Using the same data, I can produce the correct graphs that have all of the names. 
[image]

Thee following code creates the graph perfectly if I am only considering one month but if I consider more than one month the labels no longer correspond with the correct groups.

```
AdjustedData[order("Reconciled.Month", "Location", "Provider"),]
AdjustedData$Provider %>% 
  walk(~{
    filtered2_AdjustedData <- AdjustedData %>% 
      filter(Location == Location[Provider == .x]) 

    labels2 <- array(data = '',dim = nrow(filtered2_AdjustedData))
    labels2[filtered2_AdjustedData$Provider == as.character(.x)] <- as.character(.x)

h <- filtered2_AdjustedData %>% 
      ggplot(aes(Provider, Per.Visit.Bill.Rate, fill = Reconciled.Month), show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position =  position_dodge(width = .9), na.rm = TRUE)  +
  ggtitle("Per Visit Bill Rate- 2018", filtered2_AdjustedData$Location)+
  theme_light()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 22, hjust = .5, family = "serif"))+
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 18, hjust = .5, family = "serif"))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle= 0, vjust=1, hjust = .5))+
  labs(caption = "Data sourced from Provider Compensation Analysis and \nMonthly Summary of Billed Physician Encounters Reports,2018. \nRates have been adjusted to exclude the deduction per visit for malpractice insurance where applicable.")+ 
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(size= 8, hjust = .5))+ 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels2)+
  geom_text(aes(x=Provider, y= Per.Visit.Bill.Rate,label=sprintf("$%.2f",Per.Visit.Bill.Rate)), position = position_dodge(.8), hjust= 0, vjust= .5, angle = 0, size = 3)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkolivegreen3","dodgerblue3", "goldenrod2", "firebrick")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Per Visit Bill Rate ($)", limits = c(0,100),breaks =seq(0,100,10), labels = dollar)+coord_flip()+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title = "Month", reverse = FALSE))

 print(h)})
```

This code also replicates the graphs x times for x months. For example, if I am considering Jan-Apr I get 4 copies of the graphs. Additionally, some of the providers were not on hired until part way into the year so Jan may be empty. This is resulting from the fact that this code creates a vector of names which gets mismatched when it maps to the plot. I've tried every combination of na.rm and na.omit and I have made sure that providers have a blank entry in each case where they were not employed so that the bars appear correctly but no luck. I know the problem but I can't figure out a solution. I am open to completely changing my approach to doing this.

Data:

```
Provider    Reconciled Month    Per Visit Bill Rate Location
Alex    1       AZ
Daniels 1   29.08   AZ
Edwin   1   31.39   AZ
Goldberg    1   30  UT
Brown   1   25.74   UT
Bowman  1   33.54   UT
Davis   1   31.5    CA
Fenner  1       CA
Gordon  1   39.36   CA
Alex    2       AZ
Daniels 2   33.23   AZ
Edwin   2   36.63   AZ
Goldberg    2   45.22   UT
Brown   2   72.98   UT
Bowman  2   40.01   UT
Reed    2   31.67   CA
Simmonds    2   50.82   CA
Villasenor  2   27.02   CA
Alex    3   30.63   AZ
Daniels 3   40.71   AZ
Edwin   3   23.21   AZ
Goldberg    3   27.56   UT
Brown   3   33.09   UT
Bowman  3   37.26   UT
Davis   3   45.71   CA
Fenner  3   32.62   CA
Gordon  3   32.28   CA
Alex    4   49.74   AZ
Daniels 4   74.6    AZ
Edwin   4   45.83   AZ
Goldberg    4   31.67   UT
Brown   4   52.23   UT
Bowman  4   65.21   UT
Reed    4   14.25   CA
Simmonds    4   45.36   CA
Villasenor  4   36.45   CA
```

Comment: Simply this? `ggplot(data, aes(Provider, PerVisitBillRate, fill = factor(ReconciledMonth))) + 
   geom_col(position = "dodge")`

Comment: Nope @Jimbou this results in multiple occurrences of the same name.

Comment: Sorry then I don't understand your problem...and as no one else answered either, I think I'm not the only one. Thus, please revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm sure this is not the most effective method to do accomplish this, the key is to be sure of two things:
1) Make sure that all providers are accounted for in each month with the name, month, and location fields filled but the bill info left blank even if they were not on payroll for a month(s). 
2) Make sure that the providers are grouped by location and then month. After that the providers must be in the same order for each month since this method is simply creating and applying a vector of names to the axis. If the providers are listed any other way the labels will be incorrect.

This does not solve the repetition problem but at least the labels are correct now.

An added bonus: removing the

```
 filtered2_AdjustedData <- AdjustedData %>% 
  filter(Location == Location[Provider == .x])
```

and changing the appropriate references to filtered2_.. results in a de-identified overall graph for the entire company.